# Cannot access UI elements inside vaadin FileUpload FinishListener

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, vaadin

I am trying to provide capability to upload file in my vaadin application

`protected Upload questionImageUpload = new Upload("Upload question", questionReceiver);`

```
    questionImageUpload.addFinishedListener(new Upload.FinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void uploadFinished(Upload.FinishedEvent event) {
            boolean hasLock = VaadinSession.getCurrent().hasLock();
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

But, in my `FinishListener.uploadFinished()`, if I modify some UI element (in above, I disable a button), the modification does not get applied.

I assumed that this method may be invoked in a non UI thread so I checked whether `VaadinSession` is available by putting a breakpoint in `uploadFinished` above. But, `VaadinSession.getCurrent()` didn't return null. Also `hasLock` is also true.

What could be the reason?

I am running this vaadin application on Google App Engine (still running locally inside IntelliJ IDEA). Could that be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

File upload is done as a POST request to the server, containing the file data. When the upload is complete, Upload.FinishedListeners are called at the end of that POST request. While all thread locals are set up correctly, this is not a UI update request (or UIDL request) and the response which is sent to the browser only contains a text that informs the browser that the upload finished. Any UI updates done will be queued until another request asks for them.

Because of this, you need to either use @Push, so that the UI changes are pushed immediately to the client through the push channel, or enable polling at the latest when starting the upload, so that the poll request will pick up the UI changes.

Comment: I also thought about this. If this is the case, I expected that UI will get updated after some other browser request is made to server so I did some button clicks. Still, the changes done in upload finish handler didn't get reflected. (I tried to enable push but I got a hell of a lot errors from appengine)

Answer (score 0):

I actually accomplish what you want to do with a SuccedListener. I have a code which updates an embedded component with picture uploaded. You can look at the code and take a cue from it. It can also disable the button. You can correct it not optimised but it works

public class PicUploader extends Upload implements SucceededListener, Receiver {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
File file;

public String fileName;
final String LOCATION = "/home/###";

Embedded image = new Embedded();
TextField field;

public PicUploader(Embedded image, String caption) {
    this.image = image;
    this.addSucceededListener(this);
    this.setReceiver(this);
    this.setCaption(caption);

    this.setIcon(FontAwesome.UPLOAD);;

}

public PicUploader(Embedded image, TextField field) {
    this.image = image;
    this.addSucceededListener(this);
    this.setReceiver(this);
    this.field = field;
    this.setButtonCaption(""+FontAwesome.UPLOAD);
    this.setIcon(FontAwesome.UPLOAD);;

}

@Override
public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileOutputStream stream = null;

    try {
        file = new File(LOCATION
                + "/Pictures/"
                + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + filename.substring(filename.length() - 4,
                        filename.length()));
        fileName = file.getName();
        System.out.println("This is the file name " + filename);
        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return stream;
}

@Override
public void uploadSucceeded(SucceededEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    image.setSource(new FileResource(file));
    image.setVisible(true);
    image.setWidth("150");
    image.setHeight("200");
    // float ratio = image.getHeight()/image.getWidth();
    // image.setWidth(""+image.getWidth());
    // image.setHeight(""+image.getHeight());
    // field.setValue(getFileName());
    this.setEnabled(false);
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
```

}

Comment: Your code might work but in my case, if I disable a button inside either a SucceedListener or CompleteListener, button doesn't get disabled. I posted the question seeking for a reason